# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid with books details when i update a row in grid am getting Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible' error. Kindly help me to solve this error. Price Column is decimal datatype.

```
protected void grdBookDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    BookDetailsBEL.BookId = Convert.ToInt32(grdBookDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
    BookDetailsBEL.BookName = ((TextBox)(grdBookDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditBookName"))).ToString();
    BookDetailsBEL.Author = ((TextBox)(grdBookDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditAuthor"))).ToString();
    BookDetailsBEL.Publisher = ((TextBox)(grdBookDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditPublisher"))).ToString();            
    BookDetailsBEL.Price = Convert.ToDecimal((TextBox)(grdBookDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditPrice")));
    e.Cancel = true;
    grdBookDetails.EditIndex = -1;
    GetBookDetails();            
}
```

Comment: You're trying to convert a `TextBox` into a decimal on the line you're setting `Price`. You probably want to convert the text boxes' *text* into a decimal.

Comment: Yes. Can u tell me how to do that?

Comment: Reference `.Text` after you've cast it into a `TextBox` or use `ToString()`. You've done the exact same thing in the line above..

Answer (score 0):

You must use `.Text` property

```
protected void grdBookDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            BookDetailsBEL.BookId = Convert.ToInt32(grdBookDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
            BookDetailsBEL.BookName = ((TextBox)(grdBookDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditBookName"))).Text.ToString();
            BookDetailsBEL.Author = ((TextBox)(grdBookDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditAuthor"))).Text.ToString();
            BookDetailsBEL.Publisher = ((TextBox)(grdBookDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditPublisher"))).Text.ToString();
            BookDetailsBEL.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)(grdBookDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditPrice"))).Text.ToString());
            e.Cancel = true;
            grdBookDetails.EditIndex = -1;
            GetBookDetails();
        }
```

Comment: I tried as u said but i got Input string was not in a correct format In the same line.

Comment: What do you input in txtEditPrice? You must input number in txtEditPrice.

Comment: You must check txtEditPrice to be number then use Convert.ToDecimal function

Comment: I gave only number as input in txtEditPrice but dont know why this error.

Comment: If there are errors then them have to be different that error. Can I see your error?